# Why isn't my python.exe working, but the code works in IDLE?

Tags: exe, screenshot, python-idle

I am new to coding, but I was trying to create a Python code, which is able to take screenshots with some given instructions (coordinates, number of screenshots, time interval between them and the location where they will be saved). When I run it through IDLE, everything works as it should. However, when I create an exe. file, it does not work properly - I am able to input all the information in there, but the program does not do anything. Any idea, where the problem could be?

I used PyInstaller module to create exe. file and pyscreenshot module to execute the screenshots. I didn't get any errors.

Tried saving the screenshots into various locations, but I can't see those images anywhere. I was expecting it would act the same as the IDLE code.